# I am unable to find some of the features in covalent/core version 4 for Angular 12 which are found in version 3

Tags: angular7, libraries, custom-component, angular12, teradata-covalent

I am using covalent/core version 4 in my Angular 12 project and unable to find the covalent/core/loading, covalent/core/media and few more libraries which are available in the covalent/core version 3 or below. The problem is the version 3 doesn't support Angular 12 and version 4 doesn't have the libraries present in version 3 which is necessary in my project. How do I handle this? Is there any alternative library which is similar to covalent/core that supports Angular 12?

Comment: Make it an issue on their GitHub: https://github.com/Teradata/covalent/issues

Comment: Thanks. I've added the issue on their GitHub. Awaiting response.